# For which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^a}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show for which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^a}$ converges.

For $a = 0$ the series diverges

for $a < 0$ we have $\frac{1}{k^{-a}} = k^a$ and the series diverges as well, however I am not sure how to prove convergence/divergence for $a > 1$ ($a = 1$ is the harmonic series and also an upper bound for all $0 < a < 1$ so that should be sufficient)

So what I am asking is: how can I prove for which $ 1 < a < 2$ the series converges (since I know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges)

Any hints, ideas and feedback are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the tests that can show that this series is convergent for $a>1$ is *Cauchy condensation test*:

For $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ being a non-increasing sequence of non-negative numbers, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent if and only if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}$ is convergent.

For $a\ge 0$ the sequence $a_n = n^{-a}$ is non-negative and non-increasing , so we can apply this test. We have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \frac{1}{2^{na}} = \sum_{n=1}^
\infty (2^{1-a})^n$$

This is a geometric series, it is convergent iff $2^{1-a}<1$, that is $a>1$.

Answer (score 2):

For $a\leq 1$, you are correct, since for all $a\leq 1$, the series diverges. In fact, you don't need to split the three cases of $a=0$, $a<0$ and $0<a\leq 1$, because in **all** three cases, the harmonic series is a *lower* (you wrote *upper*, which was probably a typo) bound, and since the harmonic series diverges, so must all the other series.

---

For $a>1$, the easiest way of showing it would probably be the [integral test for series convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: That sounds like a good idea however the class I am taking has not yet talked about integrals yet so I would have to proof the integral test to be able to use it, is there a way of doing that another way?

Comment: @Pierre Integrals are pretty basic tools when it comes to analysis. I can't currenlty think of a simple way of proving what you need, sorry.

Comment: Without using integrals, the Cauchy condensation test also works for $a>1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly same as "P-series test" theorem.

You can see the proof [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-p-series-test)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Cauchy Integration test.It is very easy to check that integration is possible only when $a>1.$